# Which escape sequences are allowed in a string enclosed in a pair of single quotes in PHP?

Tags: php, string, backslash, html-escape-characters, single-quotes

I'm using PHP **7.1.11**

As mentioned in the PHP manual

> To specify a literal single quote in a string **which is already
>   enclosed in a pair of single quotes**, escape it with a backslash ().
>   To specify a literal backslash, double it (\). All other instances of
>   backslash will be treated as a literal backslash: this means that the
>   other escape sequences you might be used to, such as \r or \n, will be
>   output literally as specified rather than having any special meaning.

I'm not understanding the above paragraph due to which following doubts have been created in my mind :

1. Can only single quotes be specified in a string(using the escape sequence character `\'`) already enclosed in single quotes?
2. Consider the below sentence

> To specify a literal backslash, double it (\).

Actually, I can simply specify a single backslash literal by adding `single \` in a string which is already enclosed in a pair of single quotes then why the manual is saying that I have to use `double slash(\\)` to specify it?

3. Now consider the below sentence

   > All other instances of
   >   backslash will be treated as a literal backslash: this means that the
   >   other escape sequences you might be used to, such as \r or \n, will be
   >   output literally as specified rather than having any special meaning.

Does this mean that no other escape sequence character except the single quote(`\'`) can be added in a string quoted in single quotes? Will the characters like \r, \t and \n will get printed as it is like a simple text in a browser?

Someone please clarify all of my above doubts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding "first paragraph", it's about escaping backslash right before your escaped single quote

```
echo '\\\'' // Output: \'
```

All other backslashes output as it is, so there is no possibility to write "new line" symbol with single quotes.

```
echo '\n\ \'' // Output: \n\ '
```